# Using persistent layout with custom nodes and edges

Tags: java, layout, nodes, jung

I'm using the Jung library to create graphs. I want to use the persistent layout to generate the same graph every time.

I copied pasted this working code:
http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/jung-samples/xref/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/PersistentLayoutDemo.html?

And all I changed was the graph that was being created. The graph I created has custom nodes and edges. But now when I try to to restore I get (im using eclipse):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at helloworld.main.main(main.java:161)
```

And when i go to the problems view in eclipse(i was at console before) there are 2 errors:

1) Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

This is at the line:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Topology2.csv"));
```

2)Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

This is at the line :

```
PersistentLayout<nodes,Edges> persistentLayout;
```

This is my code:

```
  public class main {

  /**
  * the graph
  */public static nodes find(String a, ArrayList<nodes> b) {

    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {

        if (a.compareTo(b.get(i).name) == 0){
            return b.get(i);
        }

    }
    //System.out.println("Couldnt find node:  " + a);
    return b.get(0);
}



  /**
  * the name of the file where the layout is saved
   */
  String fileName;

  /**
  * the visual component and renderer for the graph
   */
  VisualizationViewer<nodes,Edges> vv;

  PersistentLayout<nodes,Edges> persistentLayout;

 /**
   * create an instance of a simple graph with controls to
   * demo the persistence and zoom features.
  * 
   * @param fileName where to save/restore the graph positions
   */
 public main(final String fileName)  throws Exception {
     Graph<nodes, Edges> g = new SparseMultigraph<nodes, Edges>();
        ArrayList<nodes> araylist = new ArrayList<nodes>();
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Topology2.csv"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            nodes newNode = new nodes (line);
            araylist.add(newNode);
        }
        reader.close();
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Topology.csv"));
        int counter = 0;

        while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
            counter++;
            String[] a = line.split(",");
            int number = a.length;
            //System.out.println("length: " + number);
            nodes origin =  find(a[0],araylist);
            nodes prev = find(a[1], araylist);
            if (number >= 3) {
                nodes next = find(a[2], araylist);
                g.addEdge(new Edges(counter,origin,next),origin, next);
            }
            g.addEdge(new Edges(counter,origin,prev),origin, prev);
            counter++;
        }
        reader2.close();
     this.fileName = fileName;

     // create a simple graph for the demo
     persistentLayout = 
         new PersistentLayoutImpl<nodes,Edges>(new FRLayout<nodes,Edges>(g));

      vv = new VisualizationViewer<nodes,Edges>(persistentLayout);

     // add my listener for ToolTips
     vv.setVertexToolTipTran sformer(new ToStringLabeller());
     DefaultModalGraphMouse gm = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();
      vv.setGraphMouse(gm);
      // create a frome to hold the graph
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.getContentPane().add(new GraphZoomScrollPane(vv));
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      // create a control panel and buttons for demo
      // functions
      JPanel p = new JPanel();

      JButton persist = new JButton("Save Layout");
     // saves the graph vertex positions to a file
      persist.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              try {
                 persistentLayout.persist(fileName);
              } catch (IOException e1) {
                  System.err.println("got "+e1);
            }
         }
      });
      p.add(persist);

      JButton restore = new JButton("Restore Layout");
    // restores the graph vertex positions from a file
    // if new vertices were added since the last 'persist',
     // they will be placed at random locations
     restore.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  //                PersistentLayout<nodes,Edges> pl = (PersistentLayout<nodes,Edges>)        vv.getGraphLayout();
             try {
                 persistentLayout.restore(fileName);
             } catch (Exception e1) {
                 e1.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     });
     p.add(restore);
    p.add(gm.getModeComboBox());

     frame.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     frame.pack();//setSize(600, 600);
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 /**
  * a driver for this demo
  * @param args should hold the filename for the persistence demo
 * @throws Exception 
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String filename;
     if (args.length >= 1)
         filename = args[0];
     else
         filename = "PersistentLayoutDemo.out";
     new main(filename);
 }
 }
```

Code for custom edges:

```
public class Edges {

int id;
nodes start;
nodes end;

public Edges(int id_, nodes a, nodes b) {
id = id_;
start = a;
end = b;

}

}
```

Code for custom nodes:

```
package helloworld; 
import java.io.Serializable;

public class nodes  {
String name = "";
nodes next = null;
nodes prev = null;
boolean alarm = false;
String alarmLevel = "";
String alarmCaption = "";
String alarmInfo = "";

public nodes(String na) {
    name = na;

}
public nodes(String na, String n, String p, boolean a, String lvl, String cap, String         info) {
    name = na;
    next = new nodes();
    prev = new nodes();
    next.name = n;
    prev.name = p;
    alarm = a;
    alarmLevel = lvl;
    alarmCaption = cap;
    alarmInfo = info;
}
public nodes() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

Comment: "I get java.lang.NullPointerException at a million places" is not very helpful; much more useful would be a stack trace for one of them.  If the only difference between the existing code and the new code is your custom objects, though, I'd suspect a problem with them...and you didn't include code for them, so that's not checkable.

Comment: Iv added the code for the custom nodes and edges in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the nodes constructor you're assigning next.name but never initializing next, which is null.  That's at least part of your problem.

Side note: your edge class has references to two nodes objects for no readily apparent reason, and I'm not sure what the prev and next are for in the nodes class, either.

You need to figure out what your data model is supposed to be, and bear in mind that the Graph class is keeping track of the node/edge connections.

Comment: I fixed the initializing of the next and prev nodes:
`next = new nodes();
prev = new nodes();`

The objects in the edge class were not being used so i commented them out.

I have updated the current problem in the description.

I really appreciate you helping me out.

Comment: Sorry the objects in the edge class are being used and represent the 2 nodes being connected by the edge.

Comment: The graph is already maintaining the nodes per edge; you don't need to.

Comment: But that shouldn't be a problem should it? Please see the updated description.

Comment: I just saw that you are one of the creators of jung. 

Im using this for a live network represented with nodes and edges. My end goal is that this should refresh after every 10 minutes  to create the exact same graph with the vertices in the same positions. Only the nodes will have updated information in its objects which i can use to for example change the color of the nodes to represent an alarm when the graph prints the next time. 

This would be the best way to do it right?